# Perspective division by zero yields unexpected results

Tags: directx, directx11, hlsl, perspective

Usually, this is how a shape in *clip space* is defined:

```
[0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 1.0]
[0.25, 0.75, 0.0, 1.0]
[0.75, 0.75, 0.0, 1.0]
[0.75, 0.25, 0.0, 1.0]
```

After perspective division to *NDC space* the result looks following:

[image]

However, when setting the w-component of the 2 rightmost vertices to 0:

```
[0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 1.0]
[0.25, 0.75, 0.0, 1.0]
[0.75, 0.75, 0.0, 0.0] // <-- Note that w=0 here
[0.75, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0] // <--
```

After perspective division (division of xyz components by w component), I'd expect both vertices to be "projected" to [+infinity,+infinity], since [this is how it's described on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc308050(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Divide by 0 produces +/- INF, except 0/0 which results in NaN.

However, the result doesn't indicate that. In fact, the vertices seem to be "projected" to completely different positions:

[image]

---

Any ideas of what's happening there? How would I get a hold of vertex data *after perspective divide* (stepping through the HLSL disassembly only gets me to the values in clip space)?

The reason I'm asking this is because I have actually seen this method of *setting w-component to 0* used for projecting vertices away.